# Make columns closer together

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I added three buttons in the middle of a 900px wide block each with their own column. The issue is the buttons start at the beginning and outside of the block so they are spread out way to wide.

I would love to know how to make the three buttons be close together in the middle while still having columns for the sake of mobile collapsing.

The page is here if I'm allowed to add a link. https://webhost.pro/website-builder.php

I tried to add the code here but Stackoverflow died from it.

I'm using two div-class lines. row spacing-40 and col-sm-4 for each column.

Thanks!

Comment: screenshot your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a max-width.

```
.row.center-block {
    max-width: 650px;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I ended up with 675px to keep the button text centered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Option #1 - Add .btn-block to each button**

If you add the class `.btn-block` to each of your buttons (the `<a>` elements), then each button will fill the available space of the column it lives in. The effect is that they will appear closer together.

As an added bonus, these buttons will also appear full width when they stack up on mobile. I think that most people would agree that prominent buttons like this look better on mobile when they are full width.

```
<div class="row spacing-50 center-block">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        ...<a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success">Site Builder Support</a>...
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        ...<a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Site Builder Demo</a>...
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        ...<a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-info">Web Hosting Plans</a>...
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Adding .btn-block to each <a>]

**Option #2 - Use an additional inner-row to limit the width**

Basically, right now you have three `.col-sm-4` columns in a row. If you add a second row (an inner-row), you can use the classes `.col-sm-10` and `.col-sm-offset-1` to achieve the desired effect. The new inner-row is not as wide but is still centered with the `.col-sm-10` and `.col-sm-offset-1` classes. You will change...

```
<div class="row spacing-50 center-block">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        ...
    </div>                  
</div>
```

to this...

```
<div class="row spacing-50 center-block">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Adding an extra row]

**Option #3 - Do both**

You could also add the additional row AND add the `.btn-block` class to each `<a>`. The buttons would be closer together and they would fill all space in their column (making them equal widths) and they would stack nicely on mobile screens.

```
<div class="row spacing-50 center-block">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                ...<a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success">Site Builder Support</a>...
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                ...<a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Site Builder Demo</a>...
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                ...<a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-info">Web Hosting Plans</a>...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Use additional row and add .btn-block to each button]

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using button-block because the buttons do look much better full width in mobile. Sorry I didn't choose you, I used both and the other solved the center issue first.